# Gitlab: You must accept the terms of service in order to complete action

Tags: git, gitlab

That error message appears when I try 'git fetch' in my repository. Problem is, the user who created the repo is no longer working for the company, we also can't contact him to accept the TOS. I tried creating new ssh key but it says that it's already being used. How do I solve this issue? Is there a way to make myself recognized as the creator of the repo so I can accept the TOS myself?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the [GitLab](https://gitlab.com) website and login. You have to accept the terms of service because of the new GDPR. When you've done that it should work again.

And to answer the question about yourself to be recognised as creator of the repo. The original creator can transfer the repo rights to you, so that you are the owner of the repo. But therefore you need the original owner.